# SwiftUI NavigationView layout issues

Tags: swiftui, navigationbar, navigationview

My NavigationView and Title when using SwiftUI never appear where I'd expect them to appear when run on a device or simulator.  I want them to be pretty much under the back button that is top left but when run on a device or simulator it goes quite far down the page, here is a screenshot of my simulator resized beside the preview and you can see how different this is.

[image: Navigation not looking as expected]

Here is my code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct DetailView: View {
    let tarot: Tarot
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack() {
                Image(tarot.tarotImage)
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                    .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
                    .padding(.init(top: 80, leading: 30, bottom: 80, trailing: 30))
                Text(tarot.tarotDescription)
                    .padding(.horizontal)
            }
            .navigationBarTitle(tarot.tarotName, displayMode: .automatic)
        }
    }
}

struct DetailView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        DetailView(tarot: cardsArray[0])
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't have more than one `NavigationView` in your navigation stack.

Try to remove the `NavigationView` from your `DetailView`:

```
struct DetailView: View {
    let tarot: Tarot
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image(tarot.tarotImage)
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
                .padding(.init(top: 80, leading: 30, bottom: 80, trailing: 30))
            Text(tarot.tarotDescription)
                .padding(.horizontal)
        }
        .navigationBarTitle(tarot.tarotName, displayMode: .automatic)
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked a treat thank you! I didn't realise this had already added one for me